# YOLOv5 error - 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)'

Tags: python-3.x, object-detection, valueerror, unpack, yolov5

I am running YOLOv5 on dataset which has 9 images of dog, horse and cat in training dataset and 3 images each of them in validation dataset. I am running yolov5 official colab notebook and when I ran command `!python train.py --img 640 --batch 3 --epochs 3 --data custom_data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache` I got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 667, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 562, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 253, in train
    prefix=colorstr('val: '))[0]
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 128, in create_dataloader
    prefix=prefix)
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 467, in __init__
    labels, shapes, self.segments = zip(*cache.values())
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

what may be the cause Please help!

Comment: This seems related https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/11131 I run into a similar error message and in my case I discovered that I had corrupt label files. These are the txt file with label id and relative box coordinates. I was missing the label ids.

Answer (score -2):

You are most probably not using the yolo format for the labels.
Yolo/Darknet label format is [label_index, xcenter, ycenter, w, h] (Relative coordinates)

For example:
xmin: top-left x coordinate,
ymin: top-left y coordinate,
w: bounding box width,
h: bounding box height,
w_img: image width,
h_img: image height

```
xcenter = (xmin + w/2) / w_img
ycenter = (ymin + h/2) / h_img
w = w / w_img
h = h / h_img
```

In other words your label content should not look like this:

> 0 250 150 300 400

They should look like something like this:

> 0  0.347222 0.208333 0.416666 0.555555

I recommend you checking the yolo documentary, they have explained everything there really well.
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/issues/1543